# Java ldap Search - Get all group members by group cn as input and filter members based on attribute

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Have a group like this,

```
dn: cn=Sample,ou=Groups,o=abc.com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
member: uid=guy1@mail.com,ou=People,o=abc.com
owner: uid=guy2@mail.com,ou=People,o=abc.com
```

And member and owner details like this,

```
dn: uid=guy1@mail.com,ou=People,o=abc.com
objectClass: abcEmployee
objectClass: abcPerson
objectClass: abcOrgPerson
special: specialPerson or normalPerson
```

So i want to grab status yes/no ,if the group owners and members are special or normal person or mixed in one shot.

Currently doing this check with two ldap search.

1. Getting all the members and owners from the group but cn as input.
2. pass users one by one and finding out the status of special attribute and consolidate

Is there any way i can do it in one ldap search query. Please help...

Comment: Which Java LDAP API are you planning to use? JNDI? Netscape? UnboundID? Mozilla?

Comment: Spring ldap : spring-security-ldap-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Netscape... probably